# ROUND in SQL statement vs rounding the scalar result

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is more of a style question than a coding problem.  I have a function that returns the total for a requisition based on multiplying the quantity * cost for each line item on that requisition.  The result can only have two decimal places because it is a dollar amount.

Here is my current SQL statement:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity * Cost) 
FROM LineItems
WHERE RequisitionID = @requisitionID
```

And here is my return statement in vb:

```
Return CDec(FormatNumber(selectCommand.ExecuteScalar, 2))
```

Is there any advantage to using the `ROUND()` function in the SQL statement rather than rounding the scalar result?

The code works just fine like it is, but I want to find the most efficient solution.  Thanks!

Comment: As a matter of convenience, I wouldn't use the SQL `ROUND()` function. Leave as much precision as possible and let the user of the query choose how to deal with rounding. It's difficult to predict how your code will be used in the future.

Comment: Agreed.  Even with rounding, there are different kinds of rounding (towards zero, away from zero, towards even, towards odd).  It seems silly to write different queries for each way you want to round or not round the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd rather do the rounding on the scalar result because you can still manipulate the record returned by the scalar command.

It offers flexibility for me because who knows there are some future changes on the code.